# How to apply custom theme in DevExpress?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I have created a custom theme using DevExpress theme editor and built the dll file and included it in the resources section.But how can I apply it to the application ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following help topic provided step-by-step instruction on how to apply custom theme to WPF application:
[How to: Apply a Newly Created Theme to an Application](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WpfThemeEditor/CustomDocument10603)

Related article: [WPF Theme Editor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WpfThemeEditor/CustomDocument10429)

Comment: Does that actually work for you guys? It doesn't work for me, I don't have that NewTheme directory in my hard drive, and I've edited 2 different themes.

Comment: @Carlo I believe you should talk about this with [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). Their guys can resolve practically all the issues you're running into.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        Theme theme = new Theme("MyCustomTheme", "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyCustomTheme.v12.1");
        theme.AssemblyName = "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyCustomTheme.v12.1";
        Theme.RegisterTheme(theme);
        ThemeManager.SetTheme(this, theme);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Don't forget add following namespace:

```
using DevExpress.Xpf.Core;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.But it isn't working (I guess I have to add the assembly references for that). I have found  an alternative  a solution : 
    Theme theme = new Theme("MyCustomTheme", "/DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyCustomTheme.v12.1;component/Themes/Generic.xaml") { FullName = "MyCustomTheme", AssemblyName = "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyCustomTheme.v12.1" };
But I have two obvious questions :
1. Does that affect the application portability ?
2. Is there a way to improve the theme registering time (coz i am getting a little latency when adopting this method) ?

Answer (score 1):

To set the default Theme for the whole Application you could use following line:

```
ApplicationThemeHelper.ApplicationThemeName = theme.Name;
```